# Android edittext remove focus after close and open keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

When I clicked on `EditText` , soft keyboard is showing, I can enter text. There are navigation image button in my application, when user clicks next image, `EditText` working fine.

The flow is, initially, when screen having `EditText` is loaded, soft keyboard appears, and the screen goes up adjusts focus on `EditText`, but its not happening after close keyboard & re open, it doesn't adjust screen.

**Problem is** , after entering text on edit text and closing keyboard and opening again, keyboard is hiding / covering `EditText`.

I've added following in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

In my Activity's `onCreate()` method

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

How do I show keyboard and move screen upward everytime.

Comment: remove the flags adjustResize and try

Comment: I did that also, Not worked

Comment: Are you have setBackgroundColor in code?

Comment: Edit-text area is hide or invisible?

Comment: Edit-Text is hide by keyboard

Comment: Yes. backgroud image i have set

Comment: try change different color of backgroundcolor. I have similar problem: i set color of background as color of text in textarea. But textarea will reserve a place inside view, but have "invisible" state (color text == color background)

Comment: @Piraba could you post your layout file please?

Comment: @Piraba add this in menifest **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"** or  and **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"** and  remove this **this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);** from java class

Answer (score 0):

I know this is hacky but if necessary you can use this. 
First get the height of keyboard, as it varies with device and even with in device. Then get the rootview or parentview of the layout. Whenever you click on the keyboard, set the layoutparams for this layout as you need.